# Useful Developer Resources in Second Life

Tags: linden-scripting-language

Second Life is fun to play with, and some developers are creating content there, but I was wondering what useful resources (if any) are available in Second Life for professional software developers.

- Discussion groups
- Education/training
- Vendor support
- Development-related presentations or demos
- Professional contacts

To clarify: I'm not really looking for information on developing stuff for use in Second Life (although those answers are welcome).  I am looking for pointers to stuff in SL that programmers would find useful for their real-life work.

Answer (score 2):

They have a site about some of these uses: http://secondlifegrid.net/programs/api/
and some pages on the language they kind of grew: http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LSL_Portal

Comment: I'm not looking for information on developing stuff for use in Second Life; I am looking for information on stuff in Second Life that programmers would find useful for their real lives.  (I knew this would be confusing.)

Comment: You can visit Microsoft Island. Presentations of new products are done regularly - http://www.kzero.co.uk/blog/?p=663#more-663

Answer (score 2):

I vaguely remember Dr Dobbs running some sort of ongoing "Programmer's Island" thingy in SL, but I can't find the reference right now.

Apparently some sort of "virtual conference" for software developers.

Comment: That's a click generation advertising URL.  SO shouldn't be feeding them traffic.

Comment: It was valid when I posted it. I suppose they must have let the domain lapse.

Answer (score 2):

Like you I find playing around with SL pretty interesting for recreational coding.  One of the experiences that made me think there was something to it was trying to code a working clock in a sandbox (a general building area in SL).  Other avatars would walk past and make suggestions and as there's a fair few coders around it soon turned into an interesting collaborative effort.  If only it was that simple in RL.  Some things just work really neatly in SL - I once implemented a swarming algorithm using a flock of 'birds' as the objects (which gives a whole new take on oops).

As to resources - assuming you're beyond basic coding level then you should be able to figure most things out from the LSL Wiki - http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LSL_Portal.

There's an ebook - "Scripting Recipes for Second Life" by Jeff Heaton which covers the basics in a reasonably well laid out way.  It's only a few dollars but probably only worth it if you've not done a great deal of coding elsewhere.  There's also regular classes held in-world, but I believe most of these are at a pretty basic level.

For groups I've always found the *Scripters of Second* Life group very helpful with a lot of people generally on it.  There's one called simply *Scripts* which is quite active too.

A couple of words of warning, LSL, whilst Turing-complete is pretty broken in several areas, lacks modern program constructs (and some older ones - like arrays!) and much of the 'black-art' of LSL is knowing how to work around the limitations,  With the advent of Mono though this is likely to be a decreasing issue.

Also there does seem to be an assumption by the Lindens that if you want to do any 'heavy-lifting' code you'll do it on a server off-world and call and return results to/from SL.  This isn't helped by the XMP-RPC implementation being very broken, although HTTP works fine (and generally better than might be expected).

Answer (score 1):

As far I'm concerned, I'm trying to contribute to the [OpenSim](http://opensimulator.org) project which is a OpenSource clone of the SecondLife server infrastructure, written in C# and Mono.

OpenSim is SL like, enhanced with many additional script commands, open grid protocols, with customized modules and plugins. It definitely worth a look if you dont already heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

ControlBreak suggested this in a comment (I'm promoting it to an answer):

You can visit Microsoft Island. Presentations of new products are done regularly - http://www.kzero.co.uk/blog/?p=663#more-663

Comment: Yes, that's what I should have done... +1 for you then :)

Answer (score 1):

IBM, Microsoft and Sun are pretty active in Second Life and sometimes there are interesting presentations/demos to see. Some of those are great for networking and meeting people from those companies which work on products you're interested in.

There are several groups for Java, PHP and several other programming languages apart from LSL, however IMO they're not as good resource as other non-SL resources. You can get your questions answered more quickly on StackOverflow or IRC.

IBM held several interesting programming competitions - there was something with robots finding a way out of the maze by IBM, there are also robot wars and some other programming competitions in SL, however they are all LSL-oriented.

I think I saw a beginner PHP class once, so if you're interested in learning programming language from start, try searching events and you might find something; however those are pretty rare in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

[Look & Feel team](http://swedenisland.se) Scripting, it's mine. Common 3D trouble is confusing camera center between camera or actor. A designer may think camera center is world when it should be actor.